# CGAffineTransform: rotation on UIButton resizes button image

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, rotation, cgaffinetransform

I've got a strange problem using `UIButtons`, type `custom`. I'm placing 4 of those buttons on a `UIScrollview`, rotating each button by a random angle using `CGAffineTransform`. Now it seems that the buttons themselves change size depending on the angle of rotation.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tempCtxSize);
[cookbookImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(imgOffsetX, imgOffsetY+frmOffsetY, cookbookImage.size.width, cookbookImage.size.height)];
[cookbookFrame drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0f, frmOffsetY, cookbookFrame.size.width, cookbookFrame.size.height)];
UIImage *combinedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

…

UIButton *cookbookViewButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[cookbookViewButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, combinedImage.size.width, combinedImage.size.height)];

[cookbookViewButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[cookbookViewButton setBackgroundImage:combinedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

CGAffineTransform rotation = [cookbookViewButton transform];
rotation = CGAffineTransformRotate(rotation, angle); // some random angle
[cookbookViewButton setTransform:rotation];
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a system bug:
" `Important` If a view’s transform property does not contain the identity transform, the frame of that view is undefined and so are the results of its autoresizing behaviors."

from: [Handling Layout Changes Automatically Using Autoresizing Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html)

Solution: set the parent view's autoResizeSubviews to NO.

```
    parentView.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the frame of cookbookViewButton - set the bounds.